# How do you visualise combinations versus permutations?

Tags: permutations, combinations

So I understand the two operations. But I can't seem to simply visualise the combinations versus permutations problem. Which always makes me confused when I look at the:
$ \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} $ formula. I cannot simply visualise the $\frac{1}{r!}$ factor. Surely I understand that you need it to remove the excess permutations.

If you make a simple table for $ A = \{a,b,c,d\} $ you get:

[image: Text]

So it is basically like cutting all symmetric objects out. In this case $r=2$. But I don't see how you can easily generalize this. You could make a 3d table, but is there a way to visualize it on paper like adding another column or something?

I hope someone can enlighten me.

With/without repetition: cut out the diagonal.

With/without order: cut out half of the table (half?)

How do you generalize for $r>2$

Comment: Well I *don't* visualise combinations and permutations like in that table. They can get complicated quickly if repetitions are involved, but if there are no repetitions, then it's not so hard to see what is going on. For example, the number of $5$ card hands you can get dealt from a pack of $52$ cards is $\binom{52}{5} = \frac{52!}{47!5!}.$ The number of permutations (i.e. combinations but where order also matters) is $\binom{52}{5} \times 5!\ $ because each hand can be permuted in $5!$ different ways.

Comment: Well, you are picking $r$ out of $n$ elements $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \dots \cdot (n-r+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$. If the order does not matter, you divide by $r!$ because there are that many permutations of $r$ elements.

Comment: I just think of the division by $r!$ as a kind of "structural quotient;" dividing by numbers corresponds to quotienting out structure. So when I visualize combinations v. permutations, I imagine a division-like operation.